I'm getting "could not read source map for chrome-error://chromewebdata/:" When attempting to run my Vscode app on Chrome
I am new to programming.I'm starting with html and continuing with css right now. My first codes were working but now it gives this error.My default browser was Opera. I changed it to Chrome but it didn't work.I don't know what to do

I wonder if this could help you. Also, could you share your code so we can see what potentially causes the error ?

Is this program is working on Opera browser?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Try to create files in vs-code and preview it by an extension "LIVE-SERVER" or access it from chrome
If still your facing any problem, specify that kind of problem facing!!

Hi @Sri Manikanta Yedida, welcome to SO :) If the author hasn't provided enough information or their problem isn't clear, it's best to ask for it in the comments instead of posting an answer.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
